# Drawing a simple rectangle in OpenGL 4

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

According to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Rectangles#Drawing_Rectangles) wikibook it used to be possible to draw a simple rectangle as easily as this (after creating and initializing the window):

```
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRectf(-0.75f,0.75f, 0.75f, -0.75f);
```

This is has been removed however in OpenGL 3.2 and later versions.

Is there some other simple, quick and dirty, way in OpenGL 4 to draw a rectangle with a fixed color (without using shaders or anything fancy)?

Comment: "*This is deprecated however in OpenGL 4.*" No, it has been *removed* from GL 3.2 (core profile) and above. "Deprecated" means "available, but subject to future removal".

Comment: @NicolBolas you are totally right... I corrected it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some ... way ... to draw a rectangle ... without using shaders ...?

Yes. In fact, AFAIK, it is supported on all OpenGL versions in existence: you can draw a solid rectangle by enabling scissor test and clearing the framebuffer:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(x, y, width, height);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

This is different from `glRect` in multiple ways:

- The coordinates are specified in pixels relative to the window origin.
- The rectangle must be axis aligned and cannot be transformed in any way.
- Most of the per-sample processing is skipped. This includes blending, depth and stencil testing.

However, I'd rather discourage you from doing this. You're likely to be better off by building a VAO with all the rectangles you want to draw on the screen, then draw them all with a very simple shader.

Comment: This is great... I actually want to use this for picking with the OpenGL picking "hack" (just to mark a certain rectangle with a special "color"), which makes the pixel coordinates even better for me... and also in this case performance shouldn't really be an issue since it only happens pretty rarely... (right?)

Comment: @traveh if performance doesn't matter then sure, by all means, use whatever is easiest for you.